# Insertion to a table column of a custom type which has only one element

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 10.3, I tried the following two scenarios.

1.

```
CREATE TYPE customtype AS (val VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE structdatatable(id INTEGER, structdata customtype);
```

Then executed the following insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO structdatatable VALUES(1, ('abc'));
```

This results in the following error.

```
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
```

2.

```
CREATE TYPE customtype2 AS (val VARCHAR(20), val2 VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE structdatatable2(id INTEGER, structdata customtype2);
```

Then executed the following insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO structdatatable2 VALUES(1, ('abc','def'));
```

This gets executed successfully with the following output.

```
INSERT 0 1
```

Also I executed a select statement to verify as well. Following is the result.

```
 id | structdata 
----+------------
  1 | (abc,def)
(1 row)
```

What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single value in parentheses is not automatic detected as a record. You can use the [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) syntax to make this unambiguous:

```
INSERT INTO structdatatable VALUES(1, row('abc'));
```